# Problem with docusign admin api collection

Tags: docusignapi

Problem withdocusign admin api

> I want to activate user that i added to my docusign developer account using docusign admin api collection and for that i require organization id which  i cannot find in my account profile and also there is no option to create it.Is it not available to free developer account holder?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get an Organization ID you'll need to create an Organization within your DocuSign Develeoper account. Navigate to settings and you'll see an option to get started with DocuSign Admin (if you don't see this option available you'll need to reach out to DocuSign Support to get this enabled).

Here's some documentation going over this process:

https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=tku1629136038406&topicId=nkj1583359134234.html&_LANG=enus